# Temp dictionary-style file

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, temporary-files

I"m working on a GUI application in `PyQt5`, and I'd like, on start-up, to populate the `PyQt5.QLineEdit` objects with the information that was previously used.

I tried to accomplish this goal by a creating a simple function which creates a `.txt` file for each line-edit object type (e.g., the ones responsible for image dimensions etc.) in a `./tmp` folder which is manually created (as shown in the `Naive Example`).

**Naive Example:**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path


temp_data_dict = dict(edit_line_1='temp data 1', edit_line_2='temp data 2', edit_data_3='temp data 3')
tmp_dir = Path('./tmp')
if not tmp_dir.is_dir():
    os.makedirs(tmp_dir)
with (tmp_dir / 'tmp_data.txt').open(mode='w') as temp_out:
    for idx, edit_line_key in enumerate(temp_data_dict):
        if idx < len(temp_data_dict) - 1:
            temp_out.write(f'{temp_data_dict.get(edit_line_key)}, ')
        else:
            temp_out.write(f'{temp_data_dict.get(edit_line_key)}')

with (tmp_dir / 'tmp_data.txt').open(mode='r') as temp_in:
    recovered_tmp_data = temp_in.read().split(sep=', ')
recovered_tmp_data_dict = dict()
for edit_line_key, tmp_data in zip(['edit_line_1', 'edit_line_2', 'edit_line_3'], recovered_tmp_data):
    recovered_tmp_data_dict[edit_line_key] = tmp_data
    
recovered_tmp_data_dict
```

*output:*

```
{'edit_line_1': 'temp data 1',
 'edit_line_2': 'temp data 2',
 'edit_line_3': 'temp data 3'}
```

Although it works, it is rather cumbersome to be creating a bunch of `txt` files, in my eyes, so I wondered if there is a `built-in` module which provides this functionality?

I found the `tempfile` module of the standard `Python3.8` library (as shown in `tempfile Library Example`),

**`tempfile` Library Example:**

```
import tempfile as tmp

tmp_file = tmp.TemporaryFile(mode='w+')
tmp_file.write('edit_line_1: temp data 1, edit_line_2: temp data 2, edit_line_3: temp data 3')
tmp_file.seek(0)
data_str_list = tmp_file.read().split(sep=', ')

recovered_tmp_data_dict = dict()
for data_str in data_str_list:
    edit_line_key, data = data_str.split(sep=': ')
    recovered_tmp_data_dict[edit_line_key] = data
recovered_tmp_data_dict
```

*output:*

```
{'edit_line_1': 'temp data 1',
 'edit_line_2': 'temp data 2',
 'edit_line_3': 'temp data 3'}
```

but in it I saw only methods which write to a simple file, while I'd prefer to have something more sophisticated, like a `YAML` file, where I could specify the name of the edit-line to be populated with this particular value in more of a object oriented way (i.e., `tmp_data.edit_line_1` etc.).

**My question:**

what is the best practice to save and load temporary data in `python3`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you use [QSettings](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt_qsettings.html), it will handle most of the messy details for you, and it can also serialise complex data types (basically, anything that can be stuffed into a [QVariaint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html)).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you provide a source for a comprehensible example?

Comment: I already provided a link which has pyqt examples.

Comment: Yes, I see. I meant if you could explain the way to work with this module?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. The examples in the first link are literally all there is to it. I suggest you just run them to see how simple it is. The [qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) give more details on how it alll works (e.g. [where the files will be saved on each platform](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#platform-specific-notes)).